Invert polarity of an input
I am hoping someone can help me create a simple circuit to reverse the polarity of an input.
Working with two wires, a +12V constant and a -12V which is pulsed (think turn signal light). I need to invert the output, so the it becomes a +12V pulse.
The circuit needs to handle approx. 500 mA. It has been suggested that I use a NPN transistor like a TIP31 and 560 Ω resistor. Is there any other solutions available?
Edit: Apologies for the lack of detail to the question.
To give a bit more context. The circuit is related to OE wiring on a motorcycle. The turn and brake elements have a common +12V supply for each element, the circuit is completed by the ECM on the ground side. This causes problems on aftermarket lights where there is a common ground, and a +12V wire for each element.
I need to invert my ground turn signals to a positive.
Wiring:

Black (Common Gnd)
Brown/Pink (+12V constant when running)
Pink/Dark Blue (Stop) Gnd
Dark Blue (Left Turn) Gnd
Dark Blue/Red (Right Turn) Gnd

After a bit more research, I believe this can be addressed using a PNP transistor?

You need a ground reference; where is that coming from?

Do the signal source and the receiving circuit share the same supply?

do you mean -12 V, or 0 V, which is -12 V with respect to the +12 V?

We need to agree some terminology.
In most electronics we have a reference which we call ground or GND. Voltage readings are taken with respect to GND. On your motorcycle the chassis is GND as the battery negative has been connected to it. Typically you connect your multimeter black lead to ground so that the polarity of the meter reading is correct.
Now when you ask about "+12V constant and a -12V which is pulsed" we're all immediately thinking, "Does s/he really mean -12 V or 0 V?" You mean 0 V.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The simplest solution is to use a 12 V relay to invert the logic (and not the polarity). When the relay is energised the LED circuit is grounded.
The downside of this is that you'll need three and space is a problem on the bike! The advantage is that 12 V auto relays are readily available, reasonably waterproof and use standard spade connectors that will also be available at your motor spares supplier.
